# Connect two Network segments -> Does not work

Tags: networking

I have the following networks:

192.168.174.0
192.168.50.0

Now both network segments are created by a Cisco Linksys VPN Router. To both network segments we can connect through a static IP via VPN.

Now I want to this:

I want that users connected to VPN2, which is the 50.x network to be able to reach servers form the 274.x network. To do this, I thought let's connect both VPN router with a network cable. (the lan ports). On VPN2 I setup the mode from gateway to router and created an advanced static route(192.168.274.0, Sub: 255.255.255.0, GW: 192.168.174.0)

But I am still not able to ping a machine in 174.0. Is it impossible what I want to do or where might be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

To route packets between different VLANs, enable the
Multiple VLANs option on the Multiple VLANs screen, and
then select the VLANs on the Inter-VLAN Routing screen.

Comment: more info: Inter-VLAN Routing Option
To allow packets to travel from one VLAN to another,
follow these instructions (optional):
Access the web-based utility of the RVL200. (Refer to
“Chapter 4: Advanced Configuration” for details.)
Click the DHCP tab.
Click the Inter-VLAN Routing tab.
Select the VLANs that can route packets to each other:
VLAN1, VLAN2, VLAN3, and/or VLAN4.

Comment: hmm I am not sure that this would help because we are not using VLANs.